# NextJS: Redux thunk call in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I did a POC to find a way to combine Redux with a NEXTJS application w/ Typescript

I did alot of reading and used the official docs from next [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-thunk)

And [here](https://github.com/karankumarshreds/NextReduxTS/blob/main/redux/store.ts) is what I implemented: **A simple app to fetch data from api and update reducer using THUNK**

But what I am wondering now is, is it necessary to dispatch(fetch api action using thunk) in the component itself on the client side (incase it doesn't require the client's interaction... say using a button)?

Wouldn't the right place for this be `getInitialProps` or `getStaticProps` instead of `useEffect`?

My concern is, if I were to fetch data from useEffect, then what's the point of using NextJS for SSR?!
Also, I came across this `next-redux-wrapper`, but it doesn't seem promising as it requires ALOT of boilerplate code for every reducer.

Comment: Addressing the point of not using Next with SSR.  Static props are for static pages - the data won't change after the build.  You can build a static page that fetches dynamic data - i.e., fetching in useEffect. Client-side data fetching is how React traditionally fetches data, and other frameworks like Gatsby do as well. The major benefit is building a static site (next/export) is hosting it on a CDN instead of using web servers (SSR).

Comment: SSR is great for consistency across various devices because computations, optimizations, and caching are done on your servers before it is pushed to the client in HTML.  Your goals and customer base (devices they use) should determine what to use.  In Next, you can have static pages and SSR pages.

Comment: @SeanW Let's say a user in my profile wants to view another users's profile and I decide to fetch it inside `useEffect` from the client side instead of `getInitialProps`. Would this affect the SEO performance? Or SEOs are important generally for static pages only? Like landing page etc

Comment: Yes, it affects SEO.  Some search engines would not index the client-side data.  SEO is important for content that needs to be indexed so other people can find the content.   I use client-side data fetching for all pages that don't need to be indexed.  You can keep your layout intact like sidebars and only load the content on the page.  You can also load sections of your site independently of each other.  There is flexibility with Next, you can SSR part of your page and client-side render other portions of the same page.  You can mix and match data fetching methods to fit your needs.

Comment: If your API processes the data, it will likely not affect performance.  Your side would probably feel more performant because you can have your layout intact and show data loaders that look like the content.

Comment: Ah, that makes alot of sense. For my use case, the user profile data is not indexed as it's only for logged in users to see. So I guess I'll use the SSR fetching only for public pages wherever required? Thanks again